# In Vue, how do I use the new devBaseUrl option?

Tags: vue.js

[If I'm reading this right](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/commit/1b27231361ebac1b6bcf327e5702dc48c8bd4c99), vue-cli-service, starting with v3.0.0-rc.2, has a devBaseUrl option. How do I use it?

I've specified v3.0.0-rc.2 in my package.json and the good version is installed. This could be as simple as me not knowing where to put config. I've tried adding a vue key in package.json, like this...

```
"vue" : {
  "options":{
    "devBaseUrl" : "https://notilusdev.dimosoftware.com/mobileapp/v/"
  }
},
```

but I get errors.

```
 ERROR  Invalid options in "vue" field in package.json: "options" is not allowed
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: So do you want to change the `baseUrl` for development mode?

Comment: yup. devBaseUrl is a separate option, and it's new. But that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the config  either in the file `vue.config.js` in the root of your project or a `vue` field in the package.json itself.

The option you want to modify is `baseUrl`

So in `vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/production-sub-path/'
    : 'https://notilusdev.dimosoftware.com/mobileapp/v/'
}
```

You can't do the same in `vue`field in package.json as it only takes JSON-compatible values

Reference - [vue.config.js](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js)

`

Comment: That config appends baseUrl to the url of the node dev server (http://localhost:8080). That would be fine if I just wanted to add a folder path, but I need to **replace** the node dev server with my url, so I can reverse-proxy to the node dev server.

Comment: @bbsimonbb so you want your dev server url to be  `https://notilusdev.dimosoftware.com/mobileapp/v/` instead of `localhost:8080` or you want to proxy url

Comment: yup, thats it. I modified your code so the dev value is `'\/mobileapp\/v\/'`.  So now I'm getting just the link I need to app.js (`<script type="text/javascript" src="/mobileapp/v/app.js"></script>`), but I'm staring at a blank screen and there are no errors in the console. Network tab shows that all resources are loading.

Comment: It's IIS. IIS is changing the application/javascript content-type to text-html. We'll fix that right away.

Comment: ok that appears to be working nicely. No hot module reloading yet, but I'll get there.

Comment: Take note that `baseUrl` is deprecated since Vue CLI 3.3. You can use use `publicPath` instead: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl

Answer (score 2):

BaseUrl was abolished after vue-cli.3.3, so it needs to be written as publicPath.
https://blog.csdn.net/qq_43238599/article/details/102903680 (Translate to English).

Comment: Please consider adding some of the relevant info from the blog link, to the space provided here for the answer.